# Mounting cifs drive gives: mount error(22): Invalid argument

Tags: mount, cifs

I'm trying to run:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //user.my-backup.com /mnt/wal_drive -o iocharset=utf8,rw,credentials=/etc/backupcredentials.txt,uid=postgres,gid=postgres,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770
```

However I keep on getting the following error:

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Two possible problems: your source is an URL which either may not resolve or is not advertising Samba; and, the uid/gid need to be expressed numerically. Have you read the referred `man` page?

Comment: Mount should really return a better error message.  Knowing which argument is invalid would make this error message so much more helpful.

Comment: Mount gives a generic error because the details are in the log. As it is said below, use   tail -f  /var/log/kern.log   to understand what's going on.

Comment: `dmesg | tail` tells you a bit more about which option is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a wrong URL. It should have been: `//user.my-backup.com/backup`

Comment: Some file shares stop the use of the top level. I had to pick a sub folder to mount.

Answer (score 82):

maybe this helps with this, `mount error(22): Invalid argument`... possible error is the
argument/s (mode) on mount command.

1. check your logs on the errors encountered.

   ```
   tail -f  /var/log/kern.log
   ```
2. remove the invalid argument

Comment: This worked for me. I found the error `CIFS not working, kernel upgrade:No dialect specified on mount` and resolved it by [adding] `vers=1.0` to my /etc/fstab(https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230952). I suspect it is caused by using kernel 4.13.

Comment: Jeez, thank goodness for stackoverflow.  Same problem on ubuntu.  I added vers=2.0 and it works.  Current mount.cifs is at 6.4.  Probably some enhancements to credentials but not digging into CIFS now...

Answer (score 16):

Another possible cause is the presence of `sec=ntlm` in `/etc/fstab` and it's incompatibility with newer SMB protocols like SMB3.

While not the OP's case, this can also cause `mount error(22): Invalid argument` errors, as it did for me after upgrading an old server.

Even though `kern.log` includes a suggestion to `specify vers=1.0 on mount`, it may be safer to remove or change `sec=ntlm` instead. Perhaps use the defaults to allow automatic negotiation of the SMB version and security, or specify compatible options such as `vers=3.0,sec=ntlmssp`.

Obviously this depends on your SMB server's features, but I would try and avoid `vers=1.0` unless necessary.

Comment: This worked for me. I have a Synology DS918+. Enabled SMB3 on the NAS. Set `vers=3.0` parameter and removed the `sec=ntlm` parameter. Thanks.

Comment: You answer was very helpful to me. I removed `sec=ntlm` completely and then all my drives mounted. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue on Arch Linux, with this message in log:

```
kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
```

For me the solution was to specify older version of cifs (by default it was 3.0):

`/etc/fstab`:

```
//my-router/share /media/share cifs ver="2.1",rw,soft,uid=ele,gid=ele,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,credentials=/etc/router-credentials.conf 0 0
```

Comment: Could you please explain your command? what "soft" , uid and other parts mean?

Comment: 1) `soft` - The program accessing a file on the cifs mounted file system will not hang when the server crashes and will return errors to the user application.
2) `uid` and `gid` - sets the uid that will own all files or directories on the mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership information.
3) `file_mode` and `dir_mode` works the same way as `uid` and `gid`. 
4) `0 0` these fields are not used, and by convention set to `0` 

For more information please see [mount.cifs man](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this issue was caused because I had mounted a directory full of symbolic links. After investigating the symbolic links in Windows, I got their "real" paths and mounted those instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the version information for SMB to solve the issue. What i did is i added vers=1.0. This is SMB version 1 which works with all the smb drivers. For your case it will look something like this

```
sudo mount -t cifs //user.my-backup.com /mnt/wal_drive -o iocharset=utf8,rw,vers=1.0,credentials=/etc/backupcredentials.txt,uid=postgres,gid=postgre ,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770
```

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to Jessie Debian the package must have changed.
I removed `guid=0` from the following `fstab` mount and it all worked correct again.

```
//x.x.x.x/General/  /usr/local/share/general cifs uid=0,guid=0,rw,credentials=/etc/gen-cifspasswd 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I am on CentOS I know this is Ubuntu but bear with me, this still comes top on google. People are correct to say that `mount -a` will give you the error.. on centos you then have to type `# dmesg` which will tell you what was actually wrong in detail

For me, I had to change

```
# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
# nano /etc/fstab
 ------------------------------------------------
 \\192.168.0.4\Work /mount/drive cifs user,rw,suid,uid=48,umask=0777,username=*****,password=******* 0 0
```

to

```
 # cat /etc/centos-release
 # CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)
 # nano /etc/fstab
 ------------------------------------------------
 \\192.168.0.4\Work /mount/drive cifs user,rw,suid,uid=48,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,username=*****,password=******* 0 0
```

the error I got was under `dmesg` was `CIFS: Unknown mount option "umask=0777"`

note that umask is no longer allowed

Answer (score 0):

Same error when try to mount a directory that in fact was a symbolic link.

Solution: add domain name to `search` directive in `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
search example.org
```

After that I was able to successfully mount the target.