# Finding the mount equivalent for an smb: URL

Tags: mount, lubuntu, cifs

I'm running Lubuntu 16.04.1 on my laptop. At work, I plug it into the wall with an Ethernet cable. This provides Internet access and also lets me access a directory of files (perhaps a share, or is it a server, or both?) called cchfs (`smb://cchfs`), which is used as a mapped network drive on the Windows machines here. I can see the files in cchfs by opening PCManFM, choosing Go → Network, and then opening the icons "Windows Network", "NPI_HRRP", "CCHFS" (here I'm prompted for my login details), "Root".

This all works fine, but I'd like to be able to interact with these files in zsh instead of just PCManFM, and I can't figure out how to do that. I think the first step, after creating a mount point with `sudo mkdir /media/cchfs`, is to mount the filesystem like so:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=NPI_HRRP/KArfer smb://cchfs /media/cchfs
```

but this produces the error `Mounting cifs URL not implemented yet.` From [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137011/mounting-cifs-url-not-implemented-yet-when-i-try-to-mount-a-samba-share/137022), which is about this error message, it looks like I need to replace `smb://cchfs` with `//SOMETHING/cchfs` or `//cchfs/SOMETHING`. But I don't know which, nor what the `SOMETHING` should be. I've tried a lot of guesses but only gotten pretty cryptic error messages.

**Edit 1:** Following [these instructions](https://superuser.com/a/1034654) on a Windows machine at the office, I got:

```
 C:\Users\karfer>net use
 New connections will be remembered.


 Status       Local     Remote                    Network

 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 OK           X:        \\cchfs\root              Microsoft Windows Network
 The command completed successfully.


 C:\Users\karfer>nslookup cchfs
 Server:  nsmcoint.medctr.ucla.edu
 Address:  10.2.14.10

 Name:    cchfs.cch.ucla.edu
 Address:  10.48.154.235
```

and so I tried:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=NPI_HRRP/KArfer //10.48.154.235/cchfs /media/cchfs
```

which yields `mount error(13): Permission denied` (`-v` just adds `mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.48.154.235,unc=\\10.48.154.235\cchfs,user=NPI_HRRP/KArfer,pass=********`) and in `dmesg`:

```
[ 2734.297317] Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[ 2734.297332] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
[ 2734.297591] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

I also tried `//10.48.154.235/root` in place of `//10.48.154.235/cchfs`, which didn't change anything.

I'm pretty sure I'm typing my password correctly. My password has capital letters and an exclamation point in it. Could that be a problem for `mount` although it's seemingly not a problem for PCManFM?

**Edit 2**: It looks like my credentials get accepted if I use `KArfer` in place of `NPI_HRRP/KArfer`. (It doesn't seem to make a difference whether or not I pass in `domain=NPI_HRRP` as well.) But now I get:

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.48.154.235,unc=\\10.48.154.235\cchfs,user=KArfer,pass=********
Retrying with upper case share name
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.48.154.235,unc=\\10.48.154.235\CCHFS,user=KArfer,pass=********
mount error(6): No such device or address
```

Changing `cchfs` to a few other things doesn't change anything, except that if I use `X$` in place of `cchfs`, I get `Permission denied` again.

**Edit 3**: The output of `smbclient -W=NPI_HRRP -U=KArfer -L //CCHFS` is:

```
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter KArfer's password: 
Domain=[NPI_HRRP] OS=[Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 6.1]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        IPC$            IPC       Remote IPC
        Root            Disk      
        X$              Disk      
Domain=[NPI_HRRP] OS=[Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 6.1]

        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            -------
```

However, `mount -t cifs -o username=NPI_HRRP/KArfer'%hunter2' //CCHFS /mnt`, replacing `hunter2` with my password, yields `mount error(22): Invalid argument` (after prompting for my password despite my inclusion of it in the command line). Same thing if I replace `CCHFS` with `10.48.154.235`.

Comment: The SOMETHING you refer to is the local hostname for he machine the share is on or the IP address at which that machine resides.

Comment: @ThomasWard That makes sense. How do I find that out?

Comment: Please, check this post: http://superuser.com/a/1034654

Comment: @SpasSpasov Great, thanks. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: @SpasSpasov No dice. See edit.

Comment: Maybe you should use `\!` and `\/`. Check this: http://serverfault.com/questions/309429/mount-cifs-credentials-file-has-special-character. Or according to: http://serverfault.com/a/170446/364207 you must use  `"quotes"`. Or change / add `-sec` option: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124696

Comment: @SpasSpasov These don't seem to help, at least separately (and there are too many combinations to try with blind guessing). Changing `sec` does change the error message in some cases: `Unknown error 524` for `sec=ntlmv2i` and `Invalid argument` for `sec=ntlmv2`.

Comment: I've made a test: Ubuntu 16.04 cifs mount Windows 10 shared folder. First I've tried `sudo mount -t cifs -o user=win-user,password=abc123 //192.168.1.110/Win-to-Ubuntu /mnt/test` - here it works. After changing of the password to `abc!@3` correct command is: `sudo mount -t cifs -o user=win-user,password=abc\!\@3 //192.168.1.110/Win-to-Ubuntu /mnt/test`. I think you should investigate the type of the server, but at the moment I don't have an idea how.

Comment: @SpasSpasov The need to escape `!` (at least) has nothing to do with the server. It's just that `!` is a metacharacter in the POSIX shell. Both `\!` and `\@` are resolved to the literal characters, so the backslash isn't sent over the wire.

Comment: i think your machine needs to be allowed to login to the domain , ISTR this is a machine account which is distinct from a user account.

Comment: @Amias Even though it works in PCManFM?

Comment: What you really want is the accepted answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/157128/proper-fstab-entry-to-mount-a-samba-share-on-boot the need to escape the special characters on the command line is avoided by using the credentials file as utilized in the accepted answer in the linked duplicate question.

Comment: @ElderGeek I've now tried that method. `mount -a` produces `mount error(22): Invalid argument`. The fstab line I added is `//10.48.154.235/Root /mnt/cchfs cifs credentials=/home/hippo/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,group=1000 0 0`.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/427044/mounting-cifs-drive-gives-mount-error22-invalid-argument and https://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2007/12/17/howto-mount-samba-shares-in-fstab-using-a-credential-file/

Comment: try to access a share via `smbclient`. So far, you have only listed them. When this works, use the knowledge gained for the mount line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information given, NPI_HRRP is your *workgroup*, while CCHFS is your *server*.

First thing in solving samba issues for me is to try with `smbclient` first. If I have success getting access to the share with it, I map the required information to a `mount` line.

`smbclient -U KArfer -L //CCHFS` should give you a list of available shares on CCHFS. Maybe you need `smbclient -W=NPI_HRRP -U=KArfer -L //CCHFS` if you need to enter the workgroup first.

If this works, a mount line like `mount -t cifs -o username=NPI_HRRP/KArfer%ToPsEcReT //CCHFS/x$ /mnt` should work as well. If this fails and `dmesg` shows "Unable to determine destination address.", replace `//CCHFS` with `//10.48.154.235`, the IP address of your server.

A line like `mount -t cifs -o credentials=~/.smbcredentials //10.48.154.235/x$ /mnt` might be better to avoid having your password in your bash history.

Also, [you cannot mount the "root" of a samba share](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189049/how-to-mount-the-root-file-system-of-a-windows-samba-share-with-cifs). You might be limited to the mount of X$. Or is the share's name really "Root" in your case? This is really confusing.

Comment: See my Edit 3 above.

Comment: This sounds like an authorization issue. Use a file `~/.smbcredentials`, chmod 600, with three lines: username= password= domain= and a mount option credentials=~/.smbcredentials to test.

Comment: I've tried that, too. See my comments to Elder Geek.

Comment: I have changed my mount line according to the info you gave. Try `smbclient //cchfs/x$` or `smbclient //10.48.154.235/x$`, followed by `ls`, to see if you can access the server. If this works, try the equivalent in your mount line (see my edit).

Comment: I finally got it. The line that did it was `sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/hippo/.smbcredentials //CCHFS/Root /mnt/cchfs`.

Comment: Yeah, the Root part would have been next on my list as well. Glad you got it working. cifs can be a major pita, with different solutions applicable each time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure /mnt/cchfs exists then try this:

```
 mount -t cifs -o username=youruser,password=yourpassword //10.48.154.235/cchfs /mnt/cchfs
```

Comment: This form yields the same error messages as the form I tried above.

Answer (score 0):

Try the folowing line in /etc/fstab

```
//10.48.154.235/Root /mnt/cchfs cifs credentials=/home/hippo/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

This assumes that the IP address, sharename, and contents of your credentials file are all correct. If for some reason the share isn't mounted at boot you can try mounting it at login instead by changing fstab to read

```
//10.48.154.235/Root /mnt/cchfs cifs noauto,credentials=/home/hippo/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

and putting the following in /etc/rc.local

```
mount /mnt/cchfs
exit 0
```

Sources:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

https://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2007/12/17/howto-mount-samba-shares-in-fstab-using-a-credential-file/

Comment: I found a typo in my credentials file and fixed it. However, `sudo mount -a` with this line now yields `Retrying with upper case share name` (newline) `mount error(6): No such device or address.`

Comment: I suggest that you review your fstab and credentials files for accuracy and insure the server at 10.48.154.235 is up and running.

Comment: It all seems fine to me. The server must be working because I can access it from other computers and from PCManFM on my own. It still seems to have the IP address 10.48.154.235, according to `nslookup` on a Windows machine.

Comment: @ElderGeek: This is why the step with `smbclient` is so useful. You know that the server is working, the hardware is working and the system itself can connect to a samba share. Only thing left is to fiddle with the mount options. For my workflow, making a `/etc/fstab` entry comes last. I always try to mount manually at least once, since it is much easier to debug.