# How to show other locations/local drives on left pane of file explorer?

Tags: nautilus, bookmarks

On my Ubuntu 16.04 all my local disks were on left pane of file explorer and mount with one click. On 18.04 I have to select other locations from left pane first then select the disk(partition). My question is can I somehow make it like in 16.04. Also my 3 local disks (D,E,F) all have same name when viewed in other locations. This creates further confusion.

I tried bookmarking but it doesn't auto mount clicking it. I have to mount it first time for bookmarks to work.

Edit: I am running default desktop environment gnome

I had tried something like that before! Added these line to fstab file.

`/dev/sda6 /media/user/Local Disk2 ntfs auto 0 0
/dev/sda7 /media/user/Local Disk1 ntfs auto 0 0
/dev/sda8 /media/user/Local Disk ntfs auto 0 0`

It gave me error on
$ sudo mount -a

`mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 14 -- ignored
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 15 -- ignored
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 16 -- ignored`

I think its a space issue (between local and disk). I was able to mount C drive (Contains '_').

Added image to be clear. See 150GB volume etc in the left. Would prefer this way but auto mount on start will also work.
[image: See 150 GB Volume]

Comment: Presumably then an NTFS legacy/SAMBA share?

Comment: Spot On! Dual boot windows 8.1/Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Have a look through this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092195/fstab-edit-for-nas-mount?rq=1

Comment: Please edit your question with what you have tried and what resulted. Please don't use comments to do this as they become very difficult to read when the list becomes to long.

Comment: Have you tried copy and paste the line in fstab to see if it errors?

Comment: Fstab auto mount worked. Is there any way to do like in 16.04 though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/dev/sda6 /media/user/Local Disk2 ntfs auto 0 0
```

That is seven fields. Try something like:

```
/dev/sda6 /media/user/Local_Disk2 ntfs auto 0 0
```

Take a look at `man fstab`.

Comment: I was able to auto mount on startup. But is there any way to do like in 16.04. it was much cleaner and didn't ask password when unmounting. Also was only a single click.

Comment: Instead of `auto` you could try `rw,user,noauto` -- I *think* then the disk would not mount at boot but would be mountable by regular users. You may need to also verify that the user has access to /dev/sda[n] and /media/user/Local_Disk[n].