# fstab mounting: permission setting

Tags: 18.04, mount, fstab

I have an issue with mounting my NTFS data partition (separate drive). This is the drive (`fdisk -l`):

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00095dd3

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 488396799 488394752 232,9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I mount it through a `fstab` entry with my user and my user group and full permissions:

```
/dev/sdb1    /home/asche/dtn     ntfs-3g  defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,auto,uid=1000,gid=1000           0  0
```

It shows up normally in Nautilus and in terminal (`ls -ll ~`):

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 asche asche    4096 Okt 22 21:42  dtn
```

Also all the data is there under `~/dtn`. I just don't have permission to delete, cut, rename etc (so, I guess `read-only` is granted).

Any ideas on how to change my `fstab` file? I have tried quite a bunch by now...

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Win10 in dual boot.

Comment: Please edit your question to say which version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Done! 18.04LTS :)

Comment: Thanks. You may find this link helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092195/fstab-edit-for-nas-mount?rq=1 and this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032237/why-is-mount-cifs-not-working-in-fstab-any-more-after-upgrading-from-16-04-to-18. I think you need to add vers=1.0 to fstab

Comment: Tried it - no change in behaviour though  `/dev/sdb1    /home/asche/dtn     ntfs-3g  vers=1.0,defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,auto,uid=1000,gid=1000           0  0`

Comment: Okay, your links got me on the right track! It was due to Win10 not shutting down decently in dual boot... Need to shutdown windows with pressing `SHIFT` + `Shut down` Thanks!

Comment: Excellent news. Post that as an answer to your question and then wait a few days to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows 10 partition; it "is in an unsafe state"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state)

Comment: It's not a Win 10 partition, but a partition used by both OS. But yes, the issue is the same. (also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 2):

The solution lay not in any `Ubuntu` settings, but in the dual boot with `Windows 10`. `Windows 10` has a `fast boot` option that hibernates the system instead of shutting it down decently. This results in ubuntu being able to mount the NTFS disk in read-only.

To shut down Windows 10 effectively, press `SHIFT` + `Shut down` button or follow instructions in the internet (e.g. [this tutorial](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup))

See other posts on this plattform as well, e.g. [Why does my NTFS partition mount as read only?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70281/why-does-my-ntfs-partition-mount-as-read-only)